# Mongoose: How to combine .where with $elemMatch?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's the code:

```
start = 0; end = 24
var updateQuery = schema.find({ account: accountID });
updateQuery.where( 'hour' ).gt( start ).lt( end );
updateQuery.exec( ...
```

This works fine if `hour` would be a number. In fact, it's an array holding objects with a value and an updatedBy key:
 `[{ value: 23, updatedBy: 'o45h43o8' }, ...]`

Now, I want to combine the where-query with `$elemMatch` to find out, if `hour[0].value` is between `start` and `end`. Is this doable?

Update: Clarified my question.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, you mention `hour` being a number, but also an array with `value` element fields, and then again with `v` element fields?

Comment: I tried to clarify my question. 'hour' is an array and the v is value.  Is it okay now? Sorry..

Comment: Are you specifically looking to check the `[0]` element of `hour` or all elements?

Comment: Yes. It should be the first element. Not all.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `$elemMatch` for that, you can do it using dot notation like this:

```
updateQuery.where( 'hour.0.value' ).gt( start ).lt( end );
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'd like to just see if the first element is between start and end. I tried what you suggested, but it doesn't seem to work. I thought, a dot notation would just work, if the hour contains an object but it contains an array with objects in it.

Comment: @Benjamin I did try this and it worked for me with MongoDB 2.2.3.  I think it would require at least 2.2.